# Qt5 Create qmdiArea not filling mainWindow

Tags: qt5, pyqt5

Using Qt5 creator I have a QMainWindow with a mdiArea set up under a central widget.  When I set the QMainWindow layout to vertical, the mdiArea expands to fill the MainWindow area but not completely (looks like a big border around the mdiarea).  How do I get mdiArea to fill the mainwindow and resize when mainwindow is resized?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like centralWidget has margins.  I set them all to zero to accomplish what I needed.